# How do you manually reposition faces in Mac OS X Yosemite's Photos App?

Tags: macos, applications, photos, bug

I'm not sure if this is a bug or just me missing something out, but when I try to manually add faces in my Photos app (go to photo, 'Get info', 'Add face'), a circle appears where I can name/tag the face.

When I go to drag it, however, it will ***not*** let me.

I have tried right-clicking and using all of my Ctrl, alt, cmd and shift keys. ***It will not let me drag the circle.*** The only thing I can do is name it, rename it or click the cross to delete it.

Again, I'm not sure if this is an actual bug or if I'm doing something wrong. But like this, all I can do is add circles that will pop up in random places of the photo.

No clue how to fix this, please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag anywhere in the circle to move the selection area & use the dot on the right to resize.
X on the left to cancel.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, it just doesn't let me drag it, no matter what I press, the dot included. I think it might be a bug.

Comment: hmm… all I can suggest is apply the [10.10.5 combo update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1832) [or reapply if you're already on 10.10.5] * Fix permissions, Verify & if necessary Repair disk, using Disk Utility.

* Reset Home folder permissions & ACLs using [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html)  - Maintenance tab/permissions, tick the box at the top then Execute.

Answer (score 8):

[This answer](https://discussions.apple.com/message/28374151#message28374151) in the Apple Discussions/Communities suggests that this behavior (inability to move the naming circle) is a bug in Photos; to remedy it requires restarting the Photos app ([which may not be as easy as just quitting and then double-clicking the app icon](https://discussions.apple.com/message/28378850#message28378850), perhaps requiring a system reboot).

After just experiencing this problem with Photos version 1.5 running on El Capitan (MacOS 10.11.6), rebooting worked to clear it for me.

Comment: Whenever this happens to, only a reboot will fix it.

Comment: Same here, 2 years later…

Comment: Same here, 6 years later...

Comment: Same here, 7 years later.

Comment: Hello from 2024, it's still the same