# Cannot move the "Click to Name" face circle in Photos for macOS

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app

I have many photos where the macOS Photos facial recognition / people album has not recognized a face.

I press <kbd>⌘I</kbd> to show the Info pallet, then press `+ Add Faces` to add a face circle to the Photo.

The face circle says "Click to Name" and I should be able to move and resize it.

I cannot move or resize the face circle. Attempting to grab the circle or resize handle results in a thumbnail of the photo being dragged instead, as if to share it to another app. See photo.

How can I properly move the "Click to Name" circle above the face? It does not work for any photo in my library

[image: "Click to Name" circle not moving or resizing; thumbnail dragged instead.]

macOS 12.5

Comment: I find quitting and relaunching photos corrects this for me

Comment: Sometimes it helps, if you insert the name first and then try to adjust the circle.

Comment: The related post shown in the sidebar also deals with this inability to drag the circle: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227074/how-do-you-manually-reposition-faces-in-mac-os-x-yosemites-photos-app?rq=1

Answer (score -2):

The problem here is the app is modal, and you do not have the picture window selected.

Typically this happens when you open the info panel and click somewhere in it, so it's the active window, when you then try to drag the circle it doesn't work.

The solution is to click on the image window to bring it to focus, and then the circle can be manipulated.

Note that when the Photos App auto-IDs a person, the little circle isn't editable.

Comment: It's just because the Photos app is glitchy